# we know just enough about the twilight zone to recognize its importance in maintaining a healthy ocean

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Yet the zone is poorly understood** — physically, biogeochemically and ecologically. Even the number of organisms that live there remains a mystery, let alone their diversity and function.
>
> …
>
> Here, we outline the steps needed **to ensure that enough is known about this complex global ecosystem** to inform decisions about the impacts of climate change and potential future exploitation. We call on the international marine research community to focus its attention on the twilight zone during the upcoming United Nations Decade of the Ocean, which runs from 2021 to 2030. In the spirit of the UN’s Sustainable Development Goals, we should seize the opportunity to establish a global policy that will protect this vast ecosystem for present and future generations.
>
> Carbon pump
>
> At present, **we know just enough about the twilight zone to recognize its importance in maintaining a healthy ocean.**

Does we know about the twilight zone enough or not? I’m confused

article link: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00915-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means we know (only) just enough to recognise that it is important, but we do not know enough to (properly) inform decisions.

By analogy, you are probably aware that your heart is critically important to you staying alive, but unless you are a cardiologist you probably don't understand the heart very well.